# Trying to get the correct output for requirements.txt with pip freeze?

Tags: python, python-2.7, flask, virtualenv

I am using Python 2.7 and I've just created a virtual environment using the command `virtualenv testingdir` and  inside the directory contains 4 subdirectories: `bin`, `include`, `lib`, and `local`.

I `cd testingdir` and execute `bin/pip install flask-wtf` , however when I execute `pip freeze` I get a long list of **all** the dependencies and even when I exit out of the `testingdir` directory I still get the same output when I use `pip freeze`. Can someone explain how to get only the dependencies for my virtual environment only?

Comment: Are you including your globally-installed packages in your virtual environment?

Comment: Have you activated your virtual environment?

Comment: Yes I think I may be including globally-installed packages, however I am new to flask so I'm not sure on which commands to execute to avoid including everything. EDIT: Thank you kaveh it seems that I had not activated my virtualenv

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After running `bin/pip install flask-wtf` run `bin/pip freeze`.

The comfortable way of using virtualenvs is:

```
virtualenv --no-site-packages testingdir  # not using system wide site packages
. testingdir/bin/activate # activate it
# do some stuff
pip install flask-wtf
pip freeze
deactivate # deactivate it
```

When the virtual environment is activated, command like `python` or `pip` run the executables in `testingdir/bin`.

Note that after running `pip install some_package` inside a brand new virtual environment you should not expect `pip freeze` to print only `some_package`; it will print all dependencies of `some_package` as well.